# Python - não permite atribuir valor à variável em condicional if, por quê?

Tags: python, if

Fiz algo em Python que é comum de se fazer em C e javascript, ou seja, dar uma valor a uma variável quando uma condição if é atendida. 
Tenho certeza de que em Python também é possível programar desse modo, mas, não sei porquê, não tem funcionado da forma tradicional. A variável não é aceita.
O código em questão é o que se segue:

```
#variáveis globais
N = ''
nao = 1
def jogador(N):
    if N == '':
        return '', 1
    elif N == 'X' or N == 'x' or N == 'O' or N == 'o':
        if N == 'X' or N == 'x':
            nao = 0  <- aqui deveria haver esta variável, mas ela não é aceita, fica cinza no PyCharm
            return 'X', 0 <- solução usada para dar valor 0 à variável nao
        else:
            nao = 0 <- idem
            return 'O', 0 < solução usada para dar valor 0 à variável nao
    else:
        print('Letra errada!')
        print('Tente outra vez!')
        return '', 1

while nao: <- quando fica igual a 0 o while para, bom vcs sabem disso
    print('Qual você escolhe para jogar: X ou O? ')
    N = input()
    E, nao = jogador(N) <- solução encontrada para dar o valor 0 ao nao
```

Todo o programa se resume a isso por enquanto. Estou aprendendo o Python e estou fazendo o jogo da velha.
Outra coisa, o if não aceita nenhum outro tipo de variável. Posso por var = 0 e não é aceito.
Alguém tem alguma explicação? Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em Python as variáveis externas ​​referenciadas dentro de uma função são globais apenas para leitura. Se uma variável que é global tiver um valor atribuído em qualquer lugar do corpo da função, ela será automaticamente recriada como local, **a menos** que tenha sido explicitamente declarado como `global`.

Se quer atribuir valor a uma variável global dentro de um escopo local use a palavra chave `global` antes de usar a variável.

```
#variáveis globais
nao = 1

def jogador(N):
    global nao #Declarando a variável global para uso nese escopo
    N = N.strip().upper()
    if len(N) == 1:
      if N in 'XO':
        nao = 0  
        return N      
      print('Letra errada!')
      print('Tente outra vez!')
    return ''

while nao: 
    print('Qual você escolhe para jogar: X ou O? ')
    E = jogador(input())
```

Teste o código no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/BustlingCylindricalLinkedlist

Mas eu pessoalmente não sou a favor do uso globais dentro de funções e métodos:

```
def jogador(N):
    N = N.strip().upper() 
    if len(N) == 1:
      if N in 'XO':
        return N       
      print('Letra errada!')
      print('Tente outra vez!')
    return ''

while True: 
    print('Qual você escolhe para jogar: X ou O? ')
    E = jogador(input())
    if len(E) == 1: break

print(f'O jogador escolheu {E}')
```

Teste o código no Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/WellwornMintyDatasets

---

Referencias:

- [FAQ do Programador Python: Quais são as regras para variáveis locais e globais em Python?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python)
- [Documentação Python: A declaração global](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement)

Comment: Augusto Vasques, muito obrigado pela resposta. Revi tudo o que eu li sobre escopo em Python e não vi essa informação que você me trouxe, o que me deixa preocupado em conseguir fontes completas para esse meu estudo. Outra coisa que me inquietou e me fez dormir mal, foi a forma como você resolveu a questão do N. Acostumado ao C, fiz algo tradicional nessa linguagem, mas vc me mostrou que devo pensar de forma diferente com python, o que me deixa algo desolado em relação ao conhecimento já acumulado, que deixa de ser útil. Novamente obrigado.

Comment: Desculpe desapontar, mas eu não tenho uma leitura secreta arquiva em um pendrive de emergência ou prateleira oculta na estante de livros. A única coisa que leio é a documentação oficial da linguagem  você pode ler [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) e [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python)

Comment: Sim, declarar o `nao = 1` fora das funções torna a variável global. Mas como já disse se uma variável que é global tiver um valor atribuído em qualquer lugar do corpo da função, ela será automaticamente recriada como local. Para evitar esse comportamento utilizamos a apalavra chave `global` dentro do escopo da função para avisar ao interpretador de que não recrie uma versão local da variável.